# Whyis my laptop's num keyboard not working?

Tags: keyboard

I have installed Ubuntu 17.10 and I am struggling with the laptop's num keyboard as it goes automatically OFF or ON. I am not able to find any reason why this is happening.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu.  Sorry this is rather obvious, but did you check the connectors are correctly in (assuming cable), or if wireless that there isn't something else emitting the same RF (radio-freq) nearby, or try another keyboard (if it still does it with a different keyboard, it's your pc or Ubuntu as you suspect)

Comment: @guiverc i am on laptop & also attached a DELL keyboard (new) but both keyboard are not working with NUM PADS. Thanks. Its start happening after i have installed a Tweak software & Budgie desktop environment . now i have removed Shell extension  & budgie environment. :(

Comment: I have no experience with Budgie DEsktop on Ubuntu, but i'd add that information to your question (so others who read your question will see it; assume most won't read comments; ie. 'edit' your question & add extra info such as started happening after adding tweak & budgie etc).  I wouldn't expect issues with `gnome-tweak-tool` (was it this one, or another?), but it could be related to a gnome extension (particularly an extension written for a different version of gnome/gtk+)